# How to Answer IRS Withholding Calculator Questions About 2018?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, withholding, form-w-4

I've been encouraged by my employer to recalculate my W4 allowances in light of the tax law changes for 2018.

When I use [the IRS's calculator](https://apps.irs.gov/app/withholdingcalculator) it needs me to give answers for things like, *Enter your **total 2018** contribution for...*

I'd like to update my W4 now if there's any advantage to be had, but I'm not sure how to come up with these values. Should I use the value to date? Project into the future assuming nothing changes?  Guesstimate? Wait until next year?

[image: IRS W4 Withholding calculator, page 3/5]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically give your best shot at each of these questions:

- Some of these numbers are factual, e.g. income tax withheld to date.
- Others are a matter of planning on your end, e.g. the amount of 401(k) contributions.
- Finally, the rest are projections, e.g., your gross wages for the entire 2018.

You may want to stay on the safe side, which actually means *overestimating* your income, so that you don't owe penalties for tax under-withholding.

It is a good practice to do a mid-year check and course correction. To do this, you check the year-to-date figures, project where your tax liability and your withholdings are tracking, and make changes to your allowances number if and as needed.

Comment: Thanks, I found it confusing that some numbers were snapshots of whenever I happen to use the calculator and some were projections. I guess now it's not confusing at all if I can accept that it's a calculator and has no problem with this.